# Refresh div content after OnGet method in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, jquery, razor-pages

I've got 1 data in view which is assign in OnGet method as a ViewData.

OnGet method:

```
public void OnGet(string parameter = "default")
{
    ViewData["SelectedParam"] = parameter;
}
```

My View:

```
@{
    var selectedParam= ViewData["SelectedParam"];
}

<h1>Some Page</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("MyComponent")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <div id="mainDiv">
            @selectedParam
            <hr />
            @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedParam.ToString()))
            {
                <h5>No param selected</h5>
            }
            else
            {
                <h5>@selectedParam selected</h5>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My component is sending parameter, View is changing value of ViewData["SelectedParam"] and now I want to refresh the content of a div.

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'componentElement', function () {
    var parameterResult = "test";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Index',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            parameter: parameterResult 
        },
        success: function () {            
            <!-- here I need to reload -->
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to do `location.reload()`, but I must refresh only this div, not the whole page, tried also with `$('#mainDiv').load(' #mainDiv')`, but still nothing

Comment: You want to pass ViewData using JQuery? That won't work (unless I'm missing something here). ViewData and Razor code are before page load. After the page is loaded, it's plain HTML and JS/JQuery. So you'll need to return a JSon on your OnGet, and remove and add back the div using JQuery to format it accordingly. I'll try to put together a decent answer with sources if I manage.

Comment: @CyberClaw you understood it well. I wanted to reload this div with updated value of ViewData.

Answer (score 2):

Razor evaluates the View and creates the HTML the client sees. If you examine the source code on Chrome for example, you'll notice all your Razor code was replaced with standard HTML.

If you want to modify the HTML after the page already loaded, you have 2 options. Reload page with new data, so new HTML will be created and the new conditions will be reevaluated, or use JS / JQuery to modify the page on the client side. JQuery won't have access to the ViewData though, this is pure HTML / JS. Since you don't want to reload the page, that's the only way.

Example of JQuery function that removes and adds stuff from the HTML:

```
$(document).on('click', 'componentElement', function () {
    var parameterResult = "test";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/OnGet/', //assuming controller would be Home
        type: 'POST', //if you are sending data, it's a POST
        dataType: "Json", //specify the datatype you are sending
        data: {
            parameter: parameterResult 
        },
        success: function (obj) { //notice I'm expecting an object back here
            $( "#mainDiv" ).empty(); //this will clear all the children inside the mainDiv  
            $( "#mainDiv" ).append("<h5<" + obj + " selected</h5>"); //this will add back the string you get your OnGet
        }
    });
});
```

And here is how your OnGet should be to respond to the ajax request:

```
public JsonResult OnGet(string parameter = "default") //I'll return a Json, so class needs to be JsonResult
{
    return Json(parameter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had some issues with this code (XSRF-TOKEN etc.) but finally it's working. Anyway it doesn't resolve my problem at all. ```$('#mainDiv').append('....')``` <- this line is nice, but in my project this div will have a lot of statistic info, so I have to copy all div's content and paste it to this ```append``` function? And this statistics will have many values which are depending on this 1 parameter. Maybe good way to do it will be create a Partial View for this div and on ```success(function() {})``` refresh this partial?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the better option. You could load another View into a div using jQuery using .load(url, data).  Here is an example:  $('#mainDiv').load(@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"))), parameterResult); as long as that line is inside a cshtml file (js files won't load razor), or just write the url by hand instead. The request can take your parameterResult var, and return your View, so you wouldn't even need ajax.